# How to disable the hover effect of material-ui button inside of a styled component

Tags: css, reactjs, hover, material-ui, styled-components

I added the css hover property to disable the button's hover effect, but it seems not work for my case, how should I fix this?

```
import Button from 'material-ui/Button'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  &:hover {
    background: none;
  }
`
export const SubmitButton = ({ onClick }) => {
  return (
    <StyledButton
      variant="raised"
      onClick={onClick}>
      login
    </StyledButton>
  )
}
```

Comment: sx={{ "&:hover": { backgroundColor: "transparent" }} } should work in your case.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can solve this problem by adding an inline style

```
export const SubmitButton = ({ onClick }) => {
  return (
    <StyledButton
      variant="raised"
      onClick={onClick}
      style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }} >
      login
    </StyledButton>
  )
}
```

Comment: also you have a major typo, you could have at least wrote `style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}`

Comment: Yeah, one more dirty trick needed, while they could just have it optional.

Answer (score 52):

Try setting it to the same color as the background:

```
root = {
    backgroundColor: "#FFF"
    "&:hover": {
        //you want this to be the same as the backgroundColor above
        backgroundColor: "#FFF"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 33):

this is solution for v5 if anyone needs it

```
         <IconButton
            disableElevation
            disableRipple
            size="small"
            sx={{
              ml: 1,
              "&.MuiButtonBase-root:hover": {
                bgcolor: "transparent"
              }
            }}
          >

          </IconButton>
```

Comment: Btw: This also is the way to go for the MUI Radio component because it inherits ButtonBase API.

Comment: It still works for MUI V6!

Answer (score 11):

You can try setting the background of the button as `none`

```
button: {    
    '&:hover': {
        background: 'none',
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used the origin Button component with className instead, you could have added disableRipple to the button like that.
`<Button  disableRipple>`

Comment: This does disable the effect, but not the hover.

Answer (score 0):

You can just override it via a styled component:

```
const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
    &:hover {
      background-color: transparent;
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  &&.MuiButton-root {
    &:hover {
      background: none;
    }
  }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

We can able to disable material-ui button hover effect in following way by adding these two details in the component In my case I did for Switch button.

**disableRipple**

**style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}**

```
import React from "react";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import Switch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = {
  
};

class SwitchLabels extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checked: true
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ checked: event.target.checked });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <FormControlLabel
        control={
          <Switch
            classes={this.props.classes}
            checked={this.state.checked}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            disableElevation
            disableRipple
            style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
            value="checked"
            color="primary"
          />
        }
        labelPlacement="start"
        label={this.state.checked ? "On" : 'Off'}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(SwitchLabels);
```

Answer (score -1):

Work for me

```
 <Button 
    sx={{
      color:'#000000', 
      background:'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065)', 
      width:'84px', 
      height:'51px', 
      boxShadow: '0px 0px 4px 0px #00000040',
      fontSize:'20px',
      '&:hover': {
           background:'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065)'
      },
    }} 
    variant="contained">
    +50$
   </Button>
```

Comment: OP is looking to style a button created using `styled` utility.